# Snappy Ubuntu Core Doesn't Boot

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run Snappy Ubuntu Core on my Raspberry Pi(B+ Model). I download the ZIP file off the official site, unzipped it, and then wrote the image to my 16 GB Samsung Micro SD card with WinDisk32. When I plugged in everything it showed a page with all the colors and then a blank terminal. Each screen lasted about 2 seconds and then switched to the other screen. This went on for a couple hours until I shut it down.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [download page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/):

```
Snappy Ubuntu Core 
Pi Version supported: Pi 2 only
```